# SQL iterating on same row

Tags: sql, lag

I am looking for SQL code to do this:

tab_input

| ID | Dat | A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 7 | 3 |
| a | 6 | 4 |
| a | 5 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 5 |
| b | 3 | 9 |
| b | 1 | 2 |

I want to calculate a new column B[i] = A[i] + B[i-1], but field B is reset when the ID changes

tab_output

| ID | Dat | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 6 | 4 | 5 |
| a | 7 | 3 | 8 |
| b | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| b | 3 | 9 | 16 |

I tried the following:

```
select 
       A
     , A + lag( B, 1) OVER( partition by id order by  dat ) as B 
FROM(
    select 
        ID, A, 0 as B
    FROM tab_input
    ) as base
;
```

But it doesn't work, the result is

| ID | Dat | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 6 | 4 | 4 |
| a | 7 | 3 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| b | 3 | 9 | 9 |

I think that it is adding to all the value of 0 and does not update the value of B

I am thank full your help!

Comment: Please post your expected output. Also tag the appropriate database.

Comment: Does the table also have a column to order by?

Comment: `LAG()` **requires** an `ORDER BY`. Remember, tables by definition are **unorded sets**. _There is no such thing as row order or insert order or natural order_. You could `SELECT * FROM A` 100 times and get a different order every time if the database wanted to; it's only a matter of convenience that the order **seems** to be stable. Therefore, if you want to know the previous record in a set, the only meaningful response is "based on what order?"

Comment: This is called a running total or cumulative sum. The problem is that it must run through the data in some order of course, but data in a table is unordered. You show 3,4,1,5,9, but 9,3,4,5,1 represents exactly the same data for instance. So, does the order matter or don't you care. If you care? how to determine the order?

Comment: And the most important tag for SQL requests is the DBMS you are using. You mention `LAG` and say it doesn't run. What is the error message you get? Does your DBMS support `LAG` at all? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Additionally, even if you get `LAG()` working without an order, it doesn't preserve prior values... it's still just the prior A, not the prior B.

Comment: Just use `sum(A) over (partition by ID order by Dat /* rows between unbounded preceding and current row */)` That range is the default but you can use it if that helps to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAG` looks at one row (per default the one preceding the current row). You create a B that is 0 for every row, then you look at `LAG(b)`, but b is 0 in the previous row, too; it is 0 in all rows. You expect some recursion to kick in, but this is not the case.

What you are looking for is a cumulative sum (`SUM OVER`):

```
SELECT id, dat, a, SUM(a) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dat) AS b
FROM tab_input
ORDER BY id, dat;
```